# RDLC rendered to PDF ignores Strikethrough formatting

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, rdlc

So, I have a local .rdlc file with some text formatted using strikethrough formatting.  My issue is quite simple to explain, but I do not know if it is just a limitation of PDF, or a bug with the .rdlc exporting to PDF.

When I write this code:

```
var localReport = new LocalReport();
...
byte[] pdf = localReport.Render("PDF");
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("MyReport.pdf", pdf);
```

None of the strike-through formatted text transfers over the the .pdf file properly.

If instead, I export to Word using .Render("Word"), the strikethrough does work on the .doc format.  So, I know it isn't a problem with the .rdlc report itself.

Has anyone encountered this?  Any solutions or workarounds?

Comment: I just tested in BIDS 2008R2 and the exported PDF contained the strike through. What version are you using?

Comment: Jamie, I am on SQL Server 2008, but not R2.  Maybe upgrading will be a fix.

Comment: I didn't test extensively: I just used the export to PDF built in to BIDS and had success. I just added an answer with links to a discussion of this from a couple years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/b35ca474-046d-4a38-a765-6c38c3d33105/
which suggests that missing strikethrough in PDFs was a known limitation. (But as mentioned in comments to the question, I couldn't reproduce with 2008r2.)

The two workarounds given there look painful.

> (A) finding a font which itself as the strikethrough built into each
>   glyph/character. (B) trying to mimic a strikethrough using a line
>   report item. Note that for (B) overlapping items are supported only in
>   PDF, Print & TIFF formats.

I suppose if it were mine, I would play around with option B if the text is a small amount. Also, it may be worth test some of the html passthrough enabled when a placeholder is set to render as HTML. Maybe using a strikethrough style there would work?

Comment: Thanks Jamie.  I saw that as well.  I'll mark this as the answer as the workarounds may be useful to some people, but I think the amount of code to make that work all the time is not worth it.  Rather upgrade to 2008R2.

Answer (score 1):

While exporting RDLC report on word, I faced this issue. So while fetching data I replaced style for Strike formatting with strike tag from HTML and it worked.